# glm inflated error...why?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, type-i-and-ii-errors

I'm pretty new to stats, so this may be dumb.
I've been running a bunch of models on randomly generated data to try and develop my understanding of type 1 error.

I've noticed that using `glm(family=binomial)` I get more type 1 errors than I should when giving a binomial input (a two-column matrix of success and failure). In the code below, the first loop generates a thousand logistic regression models for random data, but I get type 1 errors (p < .05) about 15% of the time!

The second loop runs the a similar thing as a Bernoulli test (just single vector of zeros and ones in the y). Here I get what I want to see, about 50 type 1 errors per 1000 models.

Can anyone explain this to me? I see that if I change the possible values for the random numbers in my success/failure y-matrix (the variable I call range here) I can lower the type 1 errors, but I don't understand why.

This gives me about triple the number of type 1 errors that I expect.

```
#Binomial glm
fit.p=c()
for(i in 1:1000){
    range=0:10
    y=matrix(sample(range,2000,replace=T),ncol=2,nrow=1000)
    x=rnorm(1000,100,50)      
    fit=glm(y~x,family=binomial(link='logit'))               
    fit.p[i]=anova(fit,test='Chisq')[2,5]                            
}
print(length(which(fit.p<.05)))
```

This works fine. About 50 errors per 1000

```
#Bernoulli glm
fit2.p=c()
for(i in 1:1000){
    y=sample(0:1,1000,replace=T)
    x=rnorm(1000,100,50)      
    fit2=glm(y~x,family=binomial(link='logit'))               
    fit2.p[i]=anova(fit2,test='Chisq')[2,5]                            
}
print(length(which(fit2.p<.05)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the first loop where you are feeding a matrix of (success/failure) to the `glm` function, the total number of trials at each replication i, is actually equal to `sum(y)` i.e. the sum of all elements of the matrix `y`. While in the 2nd loop, i.e. the Bernoulli case, the total number of trials is always set to be $1\times 1000=1000$. In the following code I used just one loop to fit booth the Bernoulli model (i.e. the fit2) and the binomial model (i.e. the fit3). This means that in one loop, I tried to get the corresponding grouped data ( in the binomial model) by using `xtabs` and the data generated for the Bernoulli case and created a matrix of (success/failure). You can see that the results are the same. Also note that I used four distinct values for `x` instead of `rnorm`.

```
> fit2.p=c()
> fit3.p=c()
> for(i in 1:1000){
+     y=sample(0:1,1000,replace=T)
+     x=sample(1:4,1000,replace=T)
+     fit2=glm(y~x,family=binomial(link='logit'))               
+     fit2.p[i]=anova(fit2,test='Chisq')[2,5]
+     cross.tab=xtabs(~y+x,data=cbind(y,x))
+     y3=matrix(c(cross.tab[2,],cross.tab[1,]),nrow=4,ncol=2)      
+     x3=1:4
+     fit3=glm(y3~x3,family=binomial(link='logit'))  
+     fit3.p[i]=anova(fit3,test='Chisq')[2,5]
+ }
> print(length(which(fit2.p<.05)))
[1] 48
> print(length(which(fit3.p<.05)))
[1] 48
```

Comment: Great thanks! That makes sense. 
So if I want to analyze data in the binomial format (as in my first example), how do I do a test which takes into account that there are actually more than 1000 data points?